# Devise error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the problem with devise: devise works well, but in devise/registration/new.html.erb I have the next string

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

that string forms error msg like ->

```
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>5 errors prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Email has already been taken</li>
    <li>Password can't be blank</li>
    <li>Phone is not a number</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The msg with all my errors formed on top of my form (over the elements of my form)
How do I create an error message beside to the element which this error occurs?

something like this

```
<div>Email<br />
    **<div class='email_error'>....</div>**
    <div class="field_with_errors">
        <input id="user_email".... />
    </div>
</div>

<div>Name<br />
    **<div class='name_error'>....</div>**
    <div class="field_with_errors">
        <input id="user_name".... />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use error_message_on for this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_message_on

You can access the error messages for each fieldname using

```
if @resource.errors[:field_name]
```

Comment: Note: "This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown here." :s